# Using data-* attribute with rails and haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a new bootstrap tab with rails and haml but when I 
trying to add a data-toggle attribute I am getting an error.

This works :

```
%a{href: '#tab2'} tab2

%a{href: '#tab2'} tab2
```

This gives me an error:

```
 %a{href: '#tab2', data-toggle: 'tab'} tab2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%a{ href: '#tab2', data: { toggle: 'tab' } } tab2
```

Or

```
%a{ href: '#tab2', 'data-toggle' => 'tab' } tab2
```

Comment: You're my new messiah. Been debugging this one for about an hour now.